# Using Django with MySQL for storing and looking up Large DNA Microarray Results

Tags: python, django, django-models, large-data

I'm trying to setup a django app that allows me to store and lookup the results of a dna microarray with ~500k unique probes for a large number of subjects.

The model set up I've been toying with is as follows:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Chip(models.Model):
    chip_name = models.Charfield()

class Probe(models.Model):
    chips = models.ManyToManyField(Chip, related_name="probes" )
    rs_name = models.CharField(unique=True)
    chromosome = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.IntegerField()

class Genotype(models.Model):
    probe = models.ForeignKey(Probe, related_name='genotypes')
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='genotypes')
    genotype = models.CharField()
```

I was wondering if there's there a better way to set this up? I was just thinking that for each subject I would be creating 500k rows in the Genotype table.

If I'm using a MySQL db, will it be able to handle a large number of subjects each adding 500k rows to that table?

Comment: 500k row is no small change; MySQL will handle hundreds of millions of rows ok, but you'll have to exercise caution querying such a table, and do it only by a highly selective index. What is stored in `Genotype.genotype`? What is the primary key of `Genotype`? How do you order records in `Genotype`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Genotype.genotype will contain a 2 letter string representing the nucleotide of each allele. I think don't really need to order the records in Genotype. I just need to be able to find the Genotype.genotype given a Subject and a Probe. I was thinking the query would be something like gt = Genotype.objects.get(subject__name="subject_name", probe__rs_name="rs_name")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you need a result (genotype) per Probe for every Subject, then a standard many-to-many intermediary table (Genotype) is going to get huge indeed.
With 1000 Subjects you'd have 500 million records.

If you could save the values for `genotype` field encoded/serialized in one or more columns, that would reduce the amount of records drastically. Saving 500k results encoded in a single column would be a problem, but if you can split them in groups, should be workable. This would reduce amount of records to nr. of Subjects. Or another possibility could be having Probe-s grouped in ProbeGroup-s and having nr. ProbeResults = nr. Subject * nr. ProbeGroup. 
First option would be something like:

```
class SubjectProbeResults(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='probe_results')
    pg_a_genotypes = models.TextField()
    ..
    pg_n_genotypes = models.TextField()
```

This will of course make it more difficult to search/filter results, but shouldn't be too hard if the saved format is simple. 
You can have the following format in genotype columns: "probe1_id|genotype1,probe2_id|genotype2,probe3_id|genotype3,..."

To retrieve a queryset of subjects for a specific genotype + probe.

a. Determine which group the probe belongs to
  i.e "Group C" -> pg_c_genotypes

b. Query the respective column for probe_id + genotype combination.

```
from django.db.models import Q

qstring = "%s|%s" % (probe_id, genotype)

subjects = Subject.objects.filter(Q(probe_results__pg_c_genotypes__contains=',%s,' % qstring) | \
                               Q(probe_results__pg_c_genotypes__startswith='%s,' % qstring) | \
                               Q(probe_results__pg_c_genotypes__endswith=',%s' % qstring))
```

The other option that I've mentioned is to have `ProbeGroup` model too and each `Probe` will have a ForeignKey to `ProbeGroup`. And then:

```
class SubjectProbeResults(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='probe_results')
    probe_group = models.ForeignKey(ProbeGroup, related_name='probe_results')
    genotypes = models.TextField()
```

You can query the genotypes field the same, except now you can query the group directly, instead of determining the column you need to search.
This way if you have for ex. 1000 probes per group -> 500 groups. Then for 1000 Subjects you'll have 500K `SubjectProbeResults`, still a lot, but certainly more manageable than 500M. But you could have less groups, you'd have to test what works best.

Comment: I do need a result per probe per subject. The data files that I'm importing are tab separated value files with probe_id|genotype where genotype is a 2 letter string. So if I'm understanding correctly you are suggesting that I use an algorithm to split the probes into groups and then store them as groups of probes. And when I'm searching retrieve the group and find my genotype results by parsing the textfield for my probe_id? I was hoping that I would be able to also return a queryset of subjects for a specific genotype and probe. Would there be anyway to do that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the answer with the edit. One last question, why do you filter Q for contains, startswith, and endswith? Will contains not cover both the other cases?

Comment: `contains=',probe_id|genotype,'` (with commas) will not match if the probe_id|genotype is the first or last entry in the text field. And `contains='probe_id|genotype'` (without commas) is not specific enough. If you're looking for probe_id = 11, it will also match for ex. '111|XX', '1111|XX' and so on

Comment: Gotcha. In my case all probe names start with "rs" followed by some numbers and Genotype can only be a combination of the letters A C G and T, so contains should do the trick. I missed the commas in the Q statement the first time around. Thanks again!